# Get wrong time when adding an event to default calendar in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, calendar, ekeventstore

Now i am working on calendar application in iPhone. I am trying to add an event to default calendar in iPhone. In this case adding an event is successfully completed.But I can't add an event in proper start time  . Start date of event is exactly correct but time is different in default calendar of iPhone.I used the following code .Please help me..

NSLog(@"start label is : %@",startLabel.text);// 2013-03-28 12:03:41 PM

```
NSLog(@"end label is : %@",endLabel.text);//2013-03-28 01:03:41 PM


     NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
     [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"];
     [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
     NSLog(@"description is : %@",[dateFormat description]);


     NSDate *sDate=[dateFormat dateFromString:startLabel.text];      
     NSDate *eDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:endLabel.text];
     NSLog(@"startDate is : %@",sDate);//2013-03-28 12:03:41 +0000
     NSLog(@"endDate is : %@",eDate);// 2013-03-28 13:03:41 +0000
     self.eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
     EKEvent *myevent = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:self.eventStore];
     myevent.title = titleFld.text;
     myevent.location  = locFld.text;
     myevent.startDate = sDate;
     myevent.endDate =  eDate;
     [myevent setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
     NSError *err;
     [self.eventStore saveEvent:myevent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];`

instead of

`[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];`

Hope this will solved your problem.

Comment: By your opinion i got start date is 2013-03-02 06:51:37 +0000 for this    start Label 2013-03-02 12:21:37 PM

Comment: How did you get endLabel.text date?

Comment: get start and end date from UIDatePicker

Comment: make sure that your date picker locale is set to Default.

Comment: comment [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]]; and try now. Because i am getting same date.

Comment: Date is okay but time is problem only in default calendar in iPhone

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26605/discussion-between-yashesh-and-user1980105)

Comment: @Yashesh, my startDate is 10-03-2019 09:00 AM , after going to event details it is displaying startDate as 10-03-2019 02:30 PM, can you please help me out.